# Spring Boot: SpringBootServletInitializer is deprecated

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to deploy Spring Boot app to JBoss by following [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file). It worked well but **SpringBootServletInitializer** is deprecated in 1.4.0.RELEASE. Which one should I use?

Maven depedency

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Java Code

```
 import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
 import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
 import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
 import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class DemoApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please clarify your question, i see that in your code u have shown u have used @springBootApplication instead of SpringBootServletInitializer . How are the 2 related ?

Comment: Yes you are right. My question is inadequate. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

You are using `org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer` this is deprecated. Instead:

## Use

`org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer`

#### For SpringBoot 2.0

`org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer`

Comment: And for spring boot 2.0.0 you need to use "org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer"

Comment: Why is it in a support package now? Is there another way to create a servlet in the new version?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this - worked for me

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializer;
```